# R: Uploading binaries with curl package

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I would like to port some code from [RCurl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) to [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) package to see if there is some efficiency gain.

Which is the equivalent of:

```
library(RCurl)
resp = postForm("https://httpbin.org/post", "fileData" = fileUpload(filename = "app.exe", contentType = "application/octet-stream"),
         .opts = list(httpheader = c(Authorization = "token 123", `Content-Type` = "application/octet-stream")))
```

or

```
curl -H "Authorization: token 123" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @app.exe "https://httpbin.org/post"
```

using the  [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html)  package?

BTW, this is what I tried:

```
library(curl)
h=new_handle()
handle_setform(h,
  c(Authorization = "token 123", `Content-Type` = "application/octet-stream"),
  fileData = form_file("app.exe", type="application/octet-stream")
)
req=curl_fetch_memory("http://httpbin.org/post", handle = h)
```

Comment: This is a tool request. Please show what you've tried and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I need further testing, but this seems to be a general working upload solution:

```
library(curl)
h=new_handle()
handle_setheaders(h,
        Authorization = "token 123",
        "Content-Type" = "application/x-dosexec"
        )

handle_setform(h,
               app = form_file("app.exe", type="application/x-dosexec"))
req=curl_fetch_memory("http://httpbin.org/post", handle = h)
```